# How do I refactor the code which contains foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to refactor the below code so that the deleted_at logic will be outside of the `foreach (var app in data)` loop. I tried to create the list `guids` and then add guids to it but its not working because `model.resources` is inside the loop and  it is still deleting all the apps.

I need `deleted_at` logic outside because I'm trying to delete all apps which are in the database but are not in new data that I'm receiving from API.

If you have a better approach on my code I would love to see that, Thank you.

```
public async Task GetBuilds()
{
    var data = new List<GetBuildTempClass>();
    var guids = new List<GetBuildTempClass>();

    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

        foreach (var app in data)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                "apps/" + app.AppGuid + "/builds?per_page=200&order_by=updated_at");
            var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject model =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject>(json);

            foreach (var item in model.resources)
            {
                var x = _DBcontext.Builds.FirstOrDefault(o =>
                    o.Guid == Guid.Parse(item.guid));

                if (x == null)
                {
                    _DBcontext.Builds.Add(new Builds
                    {
                        Guid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                        State = item.state,
                        CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                        UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                        Error = item.error,
                        CreatedByGuid = Guid.Parse(item.created_by.guid),
                        CreatedByName = item.created_by.name,
                        CreatedByEmail = item.created_by.email,
                        AppGuid = app.AppGuid,
                        AppName = app.AppName,
                        Foundation = 2,
                        Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                    });
                }
                else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                {
                    x.State = item.state;
                    x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                    x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }

                var sqlresult = new GetBuildTempClass
                {
                    AppGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid)
                };

                guids.Add(sqlresult);
            }

            //var guids = model.resources.Select(r => Guid.Parse(r.guid));
            var builds = _DBcontext.Builds.Where(o =>
                guids.Contains(o.Guid) == false &&
                o.Foundation == 2 && o.DeletedAt == null);

            foreach (var build_item in builds)
            {
                build_item.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working I added `var guids = new List < Guid > ();` list to store data, 
added `guids.Add(Guid.Parse(item.guid));` to populate the list and finally wrote  `var builds = _DBcontext.Builds.Where(o = >guids.Contains(o.Guid) == false && o.Foundation == 2 && o.DeletedAt == null);` outside the loop.

If anyone has a better suggestion please add a new answer.

```
public async Task GetBuilds() {
        var data = new List < GetBuildTempClass > ();
        var guids = new List < Guid > ();

        using(var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
            var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService < PCFStatusContexts > ();

            foreach(var app in data) {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps/" + app.AppGuid + "/builds?per_page=200&order_by=updated_at");
                var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject > (json);

                foreach(var item in model.resources) {
                    var x = _DBcontext.Builds.FirstOrDefault(o = >o.Guid == Guid.Parse(item.guid));

                    if (x == null) {
                        _DBcontext.Builds.Add(new Builds {
                            Guid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                            State = item.state,
                            CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                            UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                            Error = item.error,
                            CreatedByGuid = Guid.Parse(item.created_by.guid),
                            CreatedByName = item.created_by.name,
                            CreatedByEmail = item.created_by.email,
                            AppGuid = app.AppGuid,
                            AppName = app.AppName,
                            Foundation = 2,
                            Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    }
                    else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at) {
                        x.State = item.state;
                        x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                        x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                    }

                    guids.Add(Guid.Parse(item.guid));
                }
            }

            var builds = _DBcontext.Builds.Where(o = >guids.Contains(o.Guid) == false && o.Foundation == 2 && o.DeletedAt == null);

            foreach(var build_item in builds) {
                build_item.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }

            await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```